# How do I build Terminator?

Tags: install-from-source, terminator

I don't have admin privilege on this Ubuntu machine, and I don't see a way to build [Terminator](https://launchpad.net/terminator/+download). I found the tar.gz which contains setup.py but that is not what I want.

Can someone please guide me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you want something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812471/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-rubys-rvm).  I say this because it looks like you want binary extensions or eggs without global effect.

Then setup.py should be enough to build a user local egg.